# Generate non intersecting elements of cartesian product

Tags: combinatorics

Supposing I have a the set $C$ of all pairs of elements taken from a set S of n elements.

Given $2$ random subsets of $C$, call them $D$ and $E$, what is an efficient way to calculate all matchups between $D$ and $E$ such that there is no common element of $S$ in each matchup?

That is, I want to find all elements of the cartesian product $D\times E,\; ((d_1,d_2),(e_1,e_2))$ such that $\{d_1,d_2\}$ intersected with $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is empty, where $d_1,d_2$ are taken from $D$ and $e_1, e_2$ are taken from $E.$

For example for $n=6,\; S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and given $D = \{(1,2),(4,5)\}$ and $E = \{(1,2),(2,3),(5,6)\},\,$ the "matchup" $((1,2),(5,6))$ with $(1,2)$ taken from $D$ and $(5,6)$ taken from $E$ is valid whereas $((1,2),(2,3))$ is not since the element $2$ appears in both.

Thanks.

(If this question is too algorithmic maybe I can move it to another forum?)

Answer (score 1):

Since you know nothing about $D,E$ other than that they are subsets of $C=\binom S2$, I cannot think of much better than the following approach. For each $s\in S$ pre-compute the set $E_s=\{\, e\in E\mid e\cap\{s\}=\emptyset\,\}$, which you could represent by a bitvector of size$~|E|$. Then the subset of $D\times E$ you are after can be expressed as
$$
  \bigcup_{d=\{s,t\}\in D} d\times(E_s\cap E_t).
$$
Once the precomutation is done, this requires a single loop over $D$, and within its body a loop to find the bits that are set in the intersection.